# Solve in integers solutions

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Solve in integers
$$x^4+y^4+z^4+t^4=2020xyzt$$

What I thought: Infinite descent mod 5

Comment: What do you mean by "infinite descent mod 5"?

Comment: So you're saying the only solution is $x=y=z=t=0$?  That looks right to me.

Comment: What happened to user725958 after posing the question?

Comment: That's right, infinite descent mod 5 will do. RHS is divisible by 5, hence (insert a bit of handwaving) so is each of x, y, z, t, hence a solution divided by 5 is also a solution, hence...

Comment: And don't forget there is one integer that can be divided infinitely many times by 5 and still give an integer quotient.  Thereby the one solution that exists in integers is identified.