# Find the values in the diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-residues

> Determine whether there exists a solution for equation
>
> $a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4=(8k+7) 4^{t}(abcd+1)$
>
> where $a,b,c,d$ are positive integers, $k, t$ are non-negative
>   integers.

It seems hard; but that $(8k+7)4^t $ can be written like (1) $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2$.

I think that you can show that for (1 ) exist a $abcd-1$ thus it product is equal to $a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4$.

[Lagrange's squares and the anothers general forms]

How to solve ?

Comment: Ah, you are [back](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3445187/solve-in-integers-solutions).

Comment: @DietrichBurde As well?

Comment: What is the context of your questions with fourth powers? Are these just exercises you want to do? Or is it a competition?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Competition